# changing encoding based on input parameter in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, kannel

I have configured Kannel to send messages to my servlet. The URL is like this:

```
http://10.10.10.10/income/Submit?from=%p&to=%P&content=%a&encoding=%C
```

The problem is `encoding` is `UTF-8` for English messages and `UTF-16BE` for Persian messages. My servlet is like:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String to = request.getParameter("to");
    String from = request.getParameter("from");
    String content = request.getParameter("content");

    /* process message here */
}
```

With this code I can not get Persian messages.(They are converted to `ASCII`). When I convert `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` to `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-16BE");`, I get `null` for all variables. Can anyone help me how can I convert `to`, `from`, `content` based on `encoding` field? I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 as container.

Comment: In fact, you have to ensure that `UTF-8` exists in THREE places! Make sure that all of them are there. Here is a good explanation how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10971742/2542027

Comment: On Glassfish, `request.setCharacterEncoding()` has totally no effect on GET query strings. It only affects the POST request body. As far as I know JBoss AS >=7 is the only server which allows you to configure via its `standalone.xml` to use the same POST request body encoding for decoding of GET query string. But on all others you've to explicitly configure it separately. Therefore, your question wherein you're implying that altering the POST request body encoding has effect on GET query string decoding, is somewhat suspicious. Did you really made the right observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kannel you can set `mo-recode` to 1 in `smsbox` group. This will tell Kannel to automatically transcode text MO messages to UTF-8 charset before sending to your HTTP service.

Just ensure if your Kannel is built with iconv support.